# SQL Result into one Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wrote a sql query like this.

```
SELECT
    TR.TRAN_DATE,
    CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR='CR' THEN sum(TR.GL_TRN_AMT) ELSE 0 END AS CR,
    CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR='DR' THEN sum(TR.GL_TRN_AMT) ELSE 0 END AS DR
FROM 
    [COREBANKER1].[dbo].[GL_DAILY_TRN] AS TR 
WHERE 
    TR.GL_CODE = '01010101' 
    AND TR.BRANCH_CODE = 1000 
    AND TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2017-03-01' 
GROUP BY
    TR.TRAN_DATE, TR.CR_DR, TR.[BRANCH_CODE] 
ORDER BY 
    TR.TRAN_DATE
```

The result is this:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inqpw.png)

but I want DR CR result into one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing conditional aggregation, the `case` is the argument to the `sum()`:

```
SELECT TR.TRAN_DATE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR = 'CR' THEN TR.GL_TRN_AMT ELSE 0
           END) AS CR,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR='DR' THEN TR.GL_TRN_AMT ELSE 0
           END) AS DR
FROM [COREBANKER1].[dbo].[GL_DAILY_TRN] TR
WHERE TR.GL_CODE = '01010101' AND
      TR.BRANCH_CODE=1000 AND
      TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2017-03-01' 
GROUP BY TR.TRAN_DATE --, TR.[BRANCH_CODE] 
ORDER BY TR.TRAN_DATE;
```

I don't know if you want a separate row for each branch or not.  If you do, uncomment out the reference in the `GROUP BY`.